# Calculate elastic modulus of titanium

Tags: stresses

I would like to work out the elastic modulus of a specific grade of titanium.

Further to this I would like to learn how to calculate the maximum tensile strength of that metal in relation to its cross-sectional area.

Here is a disc of 3 inches diameter that will be spun up to high velocities. I need to calculate the elastic range and maximum tensile strength before it self destructs.

Amy help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just look in a reference for the modulus ? What grade/alloy ? What heat-treatment ? The modulus has nothing to do with the stress level where it will yield and fail.

Comment: No idea why my question was down voted. Seriously, this was a practical question and nobody actually answered it correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Centripetal force is $F= m \frac{v^2}{r}$

Therefor the acceleration $\alpha=\frac{v^2}{r}$

Let's say the titanium tensile stress is 128000psi and ignore its elongation.
it means for an infinitesimally outer ring to separate we need a force of 180000psi per linear inch of the arc of that ring. disregarding the tangential tensile stress just to get an idea.

Considering the very thin arc and a very small mass of it, this means unrealistic rotation speeds unachievable by our technology. Long before that supersonic speed of the disk will cause it to vibrate and fly off in a fiery scorching spiral.

Comment: This is nonsense. First, the maximum stress is not at the outer rim of the disk, and second, it ignores the fact that there are both radial and circumferential stresses. For a solid disk (with no central hole) the maximum stress is at the center, not at the rim.

Comment: I have to go with @kamran. Considering the performance of gas and steam turbine discs , an RPM well over 50,000 will be needed for such a small diameter.

Comment: Thanks guys. We achieved 52000 RPM. I CALCULATED the answer I needed and it was quite accurate

Answer (score 2):

Titanium modulus ranges from 15 to 18 million psi depending on alloy. Ti grades 1 to 4 are unalloyed with different levels of impurities . Grade 2 is by far the most common. Grade 5 is the most common alloy , 6 Al : 4 V. Grade 5 has a "martensite" transformation like steel ,about the only metal that does, so it can be hardened by quenching and tempering. The strength levels depend on cold work and/or heat-treatment for Ti . A hardness test will give a general level of the strength. Unless you have a mill order , random Ti is likely grade 2 or small chance of grade 5 .

Comment: Thank you. Most useful answer